# Generic not-null validator for CA1062 in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, editorconfig

I have a generic method that ensures an `IEnumerable` is not null or empty.

```
public static void IsNotNullOrEmpty<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null || !enumerable.Any())
        throw new Exception();
}
```

In `.editorconfig`, I'd like to register this method as a not-null validator for code analysis by setting `dotnet_code_quality.CA1062.null_check_validation_methods`. For non-generic methods, I can set this to:

```
dotnet_code_quality.CA1062.null_check_validation_methods = Namespace.Class.Method(ParameterType)
```

How is this done for generic validators?

Comment: Side note: when working with generic `IEnumerable<T>` try to avoid *multiple pass* (first in `Any` and then in your routine): it can result in *several* database queries, file reads with poor performance and inconsistent data.

Comment: Side note: `null` and empty are diffrent errors; I suggest throwing different exceptions for them: `if (enumerable is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enumerable));` and `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for empty `enumerable`

Answer (score 0):

I know this will not answer completely your question, it would be only a workaround, but what about removing genericity from your method ?

```
public static void IsNotNullOrEmpty(IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null)
        throw new Exception();

    var iterator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    var empty = !iterator.MoveNext();

    if (empty)
        throw new Exception();
}
```